# Hide anchor tag in URL [Ref: Rails hide #anchor tag in URL]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, redirect

I'm adopting @Old Pro's answer:

```
history.replaceState({}, '', window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#')))
```

My objectives are:

1. To redirect from Page 1 to Page 2 and jump to anchor #DivTgt
2. Once redirected, will remove #DivTgt from the URL. Therefore the URL will
           only display page2.php and not page2.php#DivTgt

@Old Pro's method works perfectly on Firefox but not on Chrome/Safari. For Chrome/Safari, it does redirect and #DivTgt removal but doesnt jump to anchor #DivTgt. @Old Pro's method is inserted on Page2 (target page).

I've tried both replaceState and pushState and both return a same result (ie only works on Firefox)

Did i miss anything.

Comment: Any running example ?

Comment: @franchez Example: on page 1 <a href="page2.php#DivTgt">Go to Page 2</a>. Then inside page 2: <Head><script type="text/javascript" >
history.pushState({}, '', window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#')))
</script></Head>

Comment: any news on your side man ?

Comment: Hey @franchez My apology. Been away, will try it out today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest to move your JavaScript code into .ready() function. Otherwise your code may be called when DOM is not yet ready.

I can not tell you why it's not working, but apparently some problems are existing with new html5 push and replace state functions due to no clear specs. Please read: [history.replaceState() example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832317/window-history-replacestate-example)

So to help you, I can propose a workaround. Keep your push/replace state function, and force scrolling to your anchor with javascript.

Can you have a look at my example please ?
http://francoisjeunesse.be/example/page1.php

Page1.php:

```
<a href="page2.php#DivTgt">Go to Page 2</a>
```

Page2.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('#DivTgt') != -1){
        document.getElementById("DivTgt").scrollIntoView(true);
    }
    history.pushState({}, '', window.location.href.substring(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#')));

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid #000;min-height:1000px">spacer</div>
<a id="DivTgt" name="DivTgt"/>anchor is here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works but it gives rise to another prblm. Not only will this jump to anchor for redirection frm page1 but will also jump all direct access to anchor (Ok-->Page1 to Page2#DivTgt; Not Ok--> Direct access to Page2,not intended to anchor). The reason i want this jump that's bcos i have a 3rd party plugin installed at #DivTgt. Therefore for any access from Page1 should jump straight to #DivTgt while direct access into Page2 shouldnt.This complication happens becos 3rd party plugin only recognizes my URL without anchor tag, it wont load if it's index.php#DivTgt. Anyway, thanks for your big help

Comment: @fanchez i think your solution works. Only left to kill is to isolate this from effecting on the direct access. Meaning the anchor jumping should only apply to Page1 --> Page2#DivTgt. While for direct access into Page 2 should not jump

Comment: @Mike Example on my website edited. Post also edited to reflect your request. Hope this helps :) Do not forget to accept my answer please.

Comment: You're welcome man. Keep this thread in bookmarks to add comments in the future if you need me on other threads :)

Comment: @franchez How can you do that in html/css? I do not have php files. How can I hide the anchor links? Should I do that in the htaccess file?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer i'm back after a long time. do you still need help ?

Comment: @franchez I have not tried dealing with this. I am still curious on how it could be done. :)

Comment: @ApoloRadomer As in my example I was using Javascript to have it working, if you replace .php with .html it will works the same. So you can even use it without server, directly in a browser. Hope this helps.