# Go back to previous page with modifed URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, browser-history

Using Javascript, I'm attempting to setup a redirect that will go back to the previous page with a newly appended value added to the url.

For example, if I landed here:

```
http://google.com/
```

Then navigated to:

```
http://google.com/redirect
```

I would expect to ultimately end up at:

```
http://google.com/?redirect=successful
```

**Javascript to head back 1 page:**

```
<script>
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

This works, but I'm not sure how I'd go about appending the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write like

```
<script>
   var a =  window.history.go(-1)+'your query string';
location.href = a;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking to go to the referrer having modified it a bit.

Then do:

```
location.href = document.referrer + "?redirect=successful"
```

(if I've got what you were looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look up the replaceState() method of the History API.

There is a simple example of its use at: http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/12/07/manipulating-browser-history-with-javascript-pushstate-replacestate

It is also discussed on StackOverflow here: [history.replaceState() example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832317/history-replacestate-example)

Comment: Try to add information itself instead of links. Links can break in future.