# Prevent Browser from saving an URL

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

My Website shows for two seconds a "Loaded!" at the start of the URL path (site.com/Loaded!/forums) without reloading the page

The problem is that the browser is currently saving the "fake" link in the history: [image: History]

Is there any way to prevent the browser to save this link?

Comment: Show some relevant code that you think might be causing the issue.

Comment: How are you showing the loaded image? Are you using a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page has code:

```
 if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);
    window.history.pushState('', 'MineLight', "Loaded!/" + Url);
    setTimeout(Back, 2000);
```

---

`window.history.pushState`:

> HTML5 introduced the history.pushState() and history.replaceState()
>   methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries,
>   respectively. These methods work in conjunction with the
>   window.onpopstate event.

You must delete it.

[Adding and modifying history entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

Comment: So if I use another method to change the url it could work?

Comment: @HAlexTM, I do not understand what you want. You want to record correct address in history browser.  Why do you need to change URL? If you remove this code will be recorded real address of the page in history page.

Comment: I'd like to show a "Loaded!" at the begin of the url's path for two seconds without saving it in history

Comment: @HAlexTM, you can try use replaceState(); 
Quote"history.replaceState() operates exactly like history.pushState() except that replaceState() modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one. Note that this doesn't prevent the creation of a new entry in the global browser history."

Comment: This could be the solution, let me test it :)

Comment: @HAlexTM - Honestly? Don't bother with that. Users don't care, or won't even notice, if the URL says 'Loaded!' for 2 seconds and then disappears. All this while you could be working on other aspects of the site that actually matter.

Comment: @HAlexTM. +1 to Marcus. But..
If you  very want, can better visualize it in the form of inscriptions or unobtrusive window to the page

Comment: @UserName it doesn't work, anyway Marcus you're right, maybe I should bother with something else..

Comment: If you wanted to, though, you could look into using a `#` hash in the URL. Does not affect history: `window.location.hash = 'Loaded!'` creates a URL like: `site.com/#Loaded!` then you can just figure a way (easily) to remove the hash after 2 seconds or whatever

Comment: @Marcus I tried, and their is no way to remove the '#'

Comment: @HAlexTM, here are examples. They are workers. 
[history.replaceState() example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832317/history-replacestate-example)