# Keep IE/FF from processing anchor during URL rewrite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

Sorry for the title, wasn't sure how to word this.

I have a nav menu at the top of my page. Clicking on each link will scroll to the targeted element.  It also appends `#sectionname` to the URL.  Everything works great in Chrome. The problem I'm having is that the menu itself is static, so when I initiate the scroll I'm offsetting the menu height.  Again, works great in Chrome, but in IE and FF it scrolls to where I want it then immediately jumps back to the top of the element minus the offset.

Here is the code:

```
$('.nav').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 77          //should actually be 78 (height of the header, but IE has a 1px discrepancy.
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;                  //causes IE and FF to jump back to the original top without the header offset.
    });
});
```

How can I keep IE and FF from immediately processing the new URL?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `history.replaceState()` to modify address string see [history.replaceState() example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832317/history-replacestate-example)

```
history.replaceState({}, target.slice(1), target);
```