# Redirect to a URL when browser back button is pressed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect, back-button

I've done some research but couldn't find a solution.

I have a landingpage.html. I want to redirect a user to anotherpage.html when he/she presses the back button in the browser.

So I've tried this code:

```
let currentUrl = location.href;
history.replaceState('', '', 'anotherpage.html');
history.pushState('', '', currentUrl);
```

It works not quite as expected: when the back button is pressed the browser address bar displays anotherpage.html page, however no actual redirection happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an event listener for `popstate` so when the user presses back it fires and you can load in that page.

```
addEventListener('popstate',()=>{location.reload()})
```

Comment: @Merger If you still need an explanation as to _why_ your code does not work as you expect, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12917772/746736

Answer (score 0):

You can use the main object window to do navigations stuff.

`window.location.href = "html page path";`

And to trigger to your button, subscribe the keyboard key

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'your key name') window.location.href = "html page path";
});
```

Comment: Keypress does not get triggered using browser back button... it is not in window or `document` context

Comment: Change the browser back button doesn’t made sense, the browser already back to the previous page. Modifying this can confuse the user.

Comment: I agree but that is what the question is about

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `location.href='<url>'`
You can check here as well [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it will allow on every browser though

```
function hackBackButton(){
location.href = "anotherpage.html";
}

history.back = hackBackButton();
```

Comment: another simple thing could be intercept the unload of the page.